# Spinner, changing on selected item

Tags: android

```
public class GraphFrame extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    Integer hoodSelector = 27;
    ArrayList<HoodData> hoodDataList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> hoodList = new ArrayList<>();
    Context mContext;

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        // Showing selected spinner item
        if(item == "Tarwewijk"){
            setHoodId(27);
        }
        else if(item == "Carnisse"){
            setHoodId(28);
            //refreshFragment();
            //getDataFromApi((GraphView) view.findViewById(R.id.graph));
        }

        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
    public void refreshFragment(){
        hoodDataList.clear();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.detach(this).attach(this).commit();
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_graph,
                container, false);
        //API Request for all the hoods

        getDataFromApi((GraphView) view.findViewById(R.id.graph));
        getDataForSpinner((Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner));
        return view;
    }

    public void setHoodId(Integer hood){
        hoodSelector = hood;
    }

    public void getDataFromApi(final GraphView graph) {
        RequestQueue rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        String url= "http://test.dontstealmywag.ga/api/damage_or_theft_car_wijk.php?hood_id=" + hoodSelector;
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // Do something with the response
                        try{
                            JSONObject o = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONArray values=o.getJSONArray("");
                            for (int i = 0; i < values.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = values.getJSONObject(i);
                                hoodDataList.add(new HoodData(jsonObject.getDouble("percentage"), jsonObject.getInt("hood_id"), jsonObject.getInt("year"), jsonObject.getString("hood_name")));
                            }

                        }  catch (JSONException ex){}
                        LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<>(new DataPoint[] {
                                new DataPoint(1, hoodDataList.get(0).getPercentage()),
                                new DataPoint(2, hoodDataList.get(1).getPercentage()),
                                new DataPoint(3, hoodDataList.get(2).getPercentage()),
                                new DataPoint(4, hoodDataList.get(3).getPercentage()),
                                new DataPoint(5, hoodDataList.get(4).getPercentage())
                                //new DataPoint(12, 0)
                        });
                        graph.setTitle("Wijk " + hoodSelector + " - " + hoodDataList.get(0).getHood_name());
                        StaticLabelsFormatter staticLabelsFormatter = new StaticLabelsFormatter(graph);

                        // set manual x bounds
                        staticLabelsFormatter.setHorizontalLabels(new String[] {"2006", "2007","2008","2009","2011"});
                        //creates custom x-axis
                        graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setLabelFormatter(staticLabelsFormatter);
                        //set nice background color :)
                        series.setDrawBackground(true);
                        //shows points at datapoints
                        series.setDrawDataPoints(true);
                        //size of the points
                        series.setDataPointsRadius(10.0f);
                        graph.addSeries(series);



                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // Handle error
                    }
                });


        rq.add(stringRequest);
    }
    public void getDataForSpinner(final Spinner spinner){
        setHoodId(28);
        RequestQueue rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        String url= "http://test.dontstealmywag.ga/api/damage_or_theft_car_wijk.php";
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // Do something with the response

                        try{
                            JSONObject o = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONArray values=o.getJSONArray("");
                            for (int i = 0; i < values.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = values.getJSONObject(i);
                                if (!hoodList.contains(jsonObject.getString("hood_name"))) {
                                    hoodList.add(jsonObject.getString("hood_name"));
                                }
                            }
                        }  catch (JSONException ex){}
                        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(spinner.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, hoodList);
                        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
                        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
                        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
                        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(GraphFrame.this);


                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // Handle error
                    }
                });


        rq.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

Some explanation to my code: I creating graph views from data generated from an API online. Now I'm having multiple hoods to create graphs of. I made a spinner which contains all the hoods which are in my API. Now when I press a spinner item I want it to change the values which are pulled from the API. This can be done by changing the hoodId. So if HoodID = 27 it gives another graph then if HoodID = 28.

So what I thought is getting the value from the spinner in onItemSelectedListener, and make a condition like

```
if(item == "Tarwewijk"){
setHoodId(28); 
}
```

This doesn't work somehow. Could anyone help me fixing the issue I'm facing.

Comment: Are you getting spinner value in item

Comment: Yes I'm getting spinner value in a item "Tarwewijk" is one of the hoods in the spinner

Comment: Try item.toLowerCase.equalsIgnoreCase("tarwewijk"); instead of ==

Comment: Tried, doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: What hoodId you are getting then

Comment: == doesn't work in Java to compare strings, you have to use string.equals(otherString);